# can TOR network ban my ip for making too many requests?

Tags: configuration, ip-address

i am using TOR to scrape .onion website.

i am making 1 request per second to be on safe side.

my question is can TOR network/specific relay server BAN my server's IP address for making too many requests in short period of time ?

what happens if something like this happens ?

will TOR installed on my machine find new relay on its own or i have to issue ?

```
service tor restart
```

every few hours for finding new relay servers ?

Answer (score 0):

Tor will not ban you but your target site can.

Comment: can relay server i am connecting to BAN my IP ? and target site cant ban my ip as i am using TOR, so my ip wont be visible to target site.

Comment: What information does the target onion site have to execute the ban?#

Comment: circuit id. Its good for blocking not much dedicated DoS attackers.

Answer (score 0):

NO, it's impossible. However - it **does not** discards the rate limits e.t.c., so - just be nice to the website you're scraping